# How to loop over results of list in jsf

Tags: jsf-2

I am new to jsf and i am trying to loop over the list in jsf. I have list of objects with (id,name). Here an id can have many names and i have to print id only once in a grid and names can repeat.

I have created a ManagedBean and retreived the lists but i am unable to figure out how i can print id only once.

Example it should print like this

```
    E.g:   Id      Names
            1       Tom
                    Tracy
                    David
            2       Stan

   @ManagedBean
   public class Details{

   List<Info> information;

   //setter which sets information 

  } 

  //info class
  public class Info{
  Long id;
  String name;
  //setters and getters
  }
```

Comment: Where you want to print ID? In Java Code only of JSF/XHTMl page I mean UI?

Comment: Yes, in UI. I have edited the question to show the example of how i would like it to be printed. Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest you build a map Map<Long, List<String>> from your list where you'll have the ID once and the list of names per each ID.

Comment: @500 Server error But I am unable to print it in ui-component. I have to print id first and then the name. But i should have empty space in id for second one and followed by name. How to make that empty. I am little behind to comprehend the ui-logic.

Comment: @TracyZirbel Which Ui-Component you Used ? It should be Datatable its simple Just Pass the list to component it will work